# Airflow:SSHHook:ERROR - not a valid RSA private key file

Tags: airflow, paramiko

Trying to connect to the SFTP server with a private key in Airflow

I have used the option private_key in the extra options

Gave connection details as below

```
    "sftp_conn_id": {
        "host": "sftp.xxxx.com",
        "login": "sftp.age",
        "password": "XXXXX",
        "port": 22,
        "conn_extra": {
          "private_key":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED

DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,B8D80099CE363B08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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
        }
      }
```

Error:

```
[2020-09-30 23:03:15,088] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - not a valid RSA private key file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 978, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/plugins/bi_plugin.py", line 4418, in execute
    ssh_hook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id=self.sftp_conn_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(StringIO(private_key))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 256, in from_private_key
    key = cls(file_obj=file_obj, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 52, in __init__
    self._from_private_key(file_obj, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 179, in _from_private_key
    data = self._read_private_key("RSA", file_obj, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 324, in _read_private_key
    raise SSHException("not a valid {} private key file".format(tag))
```

In Talend it works fine as bash as below :

```
spawn sftp -oIdentityFile=/home/talenduser/.ssh/hq sftp.age@sftp.XXXX.com
expect "sftp.age@sftp.XXXX.com's password:"
send "BuGuhbu7"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd data/\n"
expect "sftp>"
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick for me was including \n in the private key. So your json for Extra in SSH connection would look like

```
{"private_key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n***************\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to pass the conn values like:

```
{"key_file":"path/to/your/keyfile", "no_host_key_check":true}
```

Comment: There is a `: param private_key: the content of the key file to use to connect to remote_host`. I am storing the key content in secret manager and read it from there

Comment: Writing you own SSHHook implementation will make it work then

Comment: @Alenjandro , I have tried the conn values as you mentioned , I got same error as `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file
`